# numpy.unique has the problem with frozensets

Tags: python, numpy, set, frozenset

Just run the code:

```
a = [frozenset({1,2}),frozenset({3,4}),frozenset({1,2})]
print(set(a))  # out: {frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({1, 2})}
print(np.unique(a)) # out: [frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({1, 2})]
```

The first out is correct, the second is not.
The problem exactly is here:

```
a[0]==a[-1] # out: True
```

But set from np.unique has 3 elements, not 2.

I used to utilize np.unique to work with duplicates for ex (using return_index=True and others). What can u advise for me to use instead np.unique for these purposes?

Comment: Why do you want to use frosensets?

Comment: @DanielMesejo set is unhashable unlike frozenset

Comment: I know, my question was more in the lines of why just not sort each element?

Comment: so, the answer below is about this exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) operates by sorting, then collapsing runs of identical elements. Per the doc string:

> Returns the sorted unique elements of an array.

The "sorted" part implies it's using a sort-collapse-adjacent technique (similar to what the *NIX `sort | uniq` pipeline accomplishes).

The problem is that while `frozenset` does define `__lt__` (the overload for `<`, which most Python sorting algorithms use as their basic building block), it's not using it for the purposes of a total ordering like numbers and sequences use it. It's overloaded to test "is a proper subset of" (not including direct equality). So `frozenset({1,2}) < frozenset({3,4})` is `False`, ***and so is*** `frozenset({3,4}) > frozenset({1,2})`.

Because the expected sort invariant is broken, *sorting sequences of `set`-like objects produces implementation-specific and largely useless results*. Uniquifying strategies based on sorting will typically fail under those conditions; one possible result is that it will find the sequence to be sorted in order or reverse order already (since each element is "less than" both the prior and subsequent elements); if it determines it to be in order, nothing changes, if it's in reverse order, it swaps the element order (but in this case that's indistinguishable from preserving order). Then it removes adjacent duplicates (since post-sort, all duplicates should be grouped together), finds none (the duplicates aren't adjacent), and returns the original data.

For `frozenset`s, you probably want to use hash based uniquification, e.g. via `set` or (to preserve original order of appearance on Python 3.7+), `dict.fromkeys`; the latter would be simply:

```
a = [frozenset({1,2}),frozenset({3,4}),frozenset({1,2})]
uniqa = list(dict.fromkeys(a))  # Works on CPython/PyPy 3.6 as implementation detail, and on 3.7+ everywhere
```

It's also possible to use sort-based uniquification, but `numpy.unique` doesn't seem to support a `key` function, so it's easier to stick to Python built-in tools:

```
from itertools import groupby  # With no key argument, can be used much like uniq command line tool

a = [frozenset({1,2}),frozenset({3,4}),frozenset({1,2})]
uniqa = [k for k, _ in groupby(sorted(a, key=sorted))]
```

That second line is a little dense, so I'll break it up:

1. `sorted(a, key=sorted)` - Returns a new `list` based on `a` where each element is sorted based on the sorted `list` form of the element (so the `<` comparison actually does put like with like)
2. `groupby(...)` returns an iterator of key/group-iterator pairs. With no `key` argument to `groupby`, it just means each key is a unique value, and the group-iterator produces that value as many times as it was seen.
3. `[k for k, _ in ...]` Since we don't care how many times each duplicate value was seen, so we ignore the group-iterator (assigning to `_` means "ignored" by convention), and have the list comprehension produce only the keys (the unique values)

Comment: Sry if I misunderstand, but I'm talking about (a[0]==a[-1]) is True, so the resulting set should have 2 elements, not 3 as np.unique gets

Comment: I mean there is no problem with order in resulting sets

Comment: @klapeyron: Reread my answer. The problem is that `numpy.unique` *only* works if the items: 1) Overload `__lt__` to allow comparisons and 2) The `__lt__` comparison is a total ordering (so `a < b` implies `not (b < a)`, and `a < b` and `b < c` implies `a < c`). `frozenset` meets criteria #1 (if it didn't, everything would blow up immediately with a `TypeError`), but fails criteria #2 (so it silently fails to sort). The sorting is a necessary precondition for the uniquification, so when the sort doesn't work, neither does the uniquification. I've added an example of how to make it work.